# How to get roles for a custom user storage provider

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm currently attemting to extend Keycloak by implementing a custom user storage provider. I've connected to a custom database and was able to authenticate users using it. What I would like to do is know how and which methods should I implement to get user roles into my keycloak realm via this custom provider? thanks appreciate any idea about this.

Comment: it seems that you want to import users (along with their roles) from external auth. provider to Keycloak. Correct?

Comment: @user1264304 Yes that is correct, I tried using custom authenticators and implementing a custom user storage provider based on Thomas Darimont's git repo (https://github.com/thomasdarimont), it was a good place of entry but couldn't find how to map it with the Keycloak UI function events. By function events I mean Keycloak Role tabs and its UI for an instance.